# Excluding a specific machine from Group Policy - Server Essentials 2012

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-essentials

Server OS: Server Essentials 2012
Client OS Windows 8.1

I have a domain set up using SE 2012 and have used the group Policy wizard to apply Folder Redirection and "Security Settings".

Can I make an exception for a specific machine so that Folder Redirection and Windows Update settings are not applied for that machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  There a few basic approaches to his problem.

1. Organization Units (OUs)

   - You can use OUs to control which computers get which policies, either [by linking different group policies to different OUs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732979.aspx), or by [blocking inheritance in some OUs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731076.aspx).
2. Filtering

   - You can use either [WMI filtering](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779036%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) or [Security Filtering](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781988%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to force GPOs to apply or not apply to given computer and/or user object(s).
3. [Group Policy Precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785665%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

   - Not all group policy objects have the same precedence.  You can use this to have a desired group policy effectively overrule an undesired one.

Comment: Filtering sounds like the easiet. Is there a walkthrough for "a-developer-who-fancies-himself-as-a-domain--admin" :-)

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee [Here's a Link to a basic walk-through on WMI filtering for OSes on technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/09/11/fun-with-wmi-filters-in-group-policy.aspx).  Security filtering's pretty straightforward, but there's no easy way to do a simple `NOT` with security filtering.  So, I'd stick with the WMI filter - decide how you want to filter out your specific machine  (OS, hostname, hardware, whatever), write your query (not sure you'll need help, as a dev, but Google is very helpful for most WMI queries), and apply that query to your GPO.

Comment: +1 WMI filtering worked for me in Server 2003.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Delegation-tab of the policy you want to exclude and add the computer you do not want to apply the policy to, to the list. Select the server on the Delegation tab, click the 'Advanced' button, and set the 'Apply Group Policy' setting to 'Deny'. Now, this server is excluded from this policy without moving it or blocking inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You apply group policy through the organizational unit (OU) in active directories. for example, a OU called computers has the policies you need. To exclude a computer from the policies, move it out of the OU called computers.

Comment: I have Server Essentials 2012. Do I used gpedit? I did have a look but could not see how to exclude the computer